# How do I declare that my attributes belong to some type class in a record?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, record

I want to say that my record attributes have to belong to a type class so they are not constrained to a specific type within that type class. My code example of what I want to do:

```
data Complex = Complex {
    real :: Num a => a,
    imag :: Num b => b
}
```

Is this possible, if so, how?

Comment: That is possible, with `ExistentialQuantification`, you can write `data Complex a b = (Num a, Num b) => Complex { real :: a, imag :: b }`, but is often considered a *misfeature*. It is probably better to use GADTs.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I don't think anyone considers existential quantification a misfeature. Just this sort of application is generally ill-advised. A better example of their use: `Coyoneda`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Are you thinking of the legacy `DatatypeContexts`? E.g. `data (Num a, Num b) => Complex a b = Complex { … }`. It was deprecated in GHC 7.2, since it wasn’t very useful—all it did was require `Num` on any functions that used `Complex`, whether they needed it or not. I agree that `GADTs` are better than `ExistentialQuantification`, though, if only because they’re more general and imo more readable. (In fact I’ve started taking to using `GADTSyntax` for all datatypes, since it’s more regular and explicit, and makes it easier to turn a type into a GADT later.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, you would parameterize the type itself

```
data Complex a b = Complex { real :: a, image :: b }
```

or more likely

```
data Complex a = Complex { real :: a, image :: a }
```

and put the constraints on any function that uses the type:

```
foo :: Num a => Complex a -> a
foo c = 3 * real c - 5 * imag c
```

or

```
bar :: Num a => Complex a -> Complex a
bar (Complex r i) = Complex (3 * r) (negate (5 * i))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that I will use a function to construct my records, and export only that function instead of the constructor, so it's type safe.

Comment: @freestyle Thanks for the edit. I added another example that matches what I imagined I was doing before :)